# How can i get current date and time inside async python-function?

Tags: python, date, asynchronous, time, aiogram

I need to get current date and time in async function. How can i do so?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def command_start(message: types.message):
    # Получение данных о пользователе (id, name) для последующей записи в БД.
    person_id = message.from_user.id
    person_name = message.from_user.full_name

    # Создание пула соединений.
    connection_pool = await create_asyncpg_connection_pool()

    # Если person_id и person_name записаны, то далее происходит подключение к БД.
    if person_id and person_name:
        # Блок except необходим для корректного отображения ошибки.
        try:
            # Получение асинхронного соединения из пула.
            async with connection_pool.acquire() as connection:
                # Начало асинхронной транзакции. Объект cursor не требуется.
                async with connection.transaction():
                    # Проверка, существует ли пользователь в базе данных.
                    user_exists = await connection.fetchval("SELECT 1 FROM user_data WHERE user_id = $1", person_id)
                    # Если пользователь не существует, добавляем его в базу данных.
                    if not user_exists:
                        await connection.execute("INSERT INTO user_data (user_id, username) VALUES ($1, $2)", person_id,
                                                 person_name)
        except Exception as error:
            # Блок except необходим для корректного отображения ошибки.
            print(error)

    
    await message.answer(some text)
```

Didn't try anything cuz of lack of information :( Pls, help me. I'm new to python.

Comment: Same way you would in any other function, `datetime`

Comment: but won't it destroy asynchrony?

Comment: What is asynchrony anyway.....

Comment: Calling a long running synchronous function (in the same thread) would create problems but not one that returns quickly.

Comment: ty so much, Michael :)

Comment: Note that there is a problem with the code because it catches and handles all exceptions, potentially masking and mishandling errors in unexpected ways.

Comment: do I need to move the exception block lower? @PéterSzilvási

Comment: @fishlover12345 No, I was pointing out that you should catch only specific exceptions and run specific error-recovering mechanisms. For example, if you have an `IOError` exception then you handle the I/O related error cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets the current date time:

```py
now = datetime.now()
print("now =", now)
```

Or even you can format it with:

```py
# dd/mm/YY H:M:S
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print("date and time =", dt_string)
```

This is how to get the current date:

```
today = date.today()
print("Today's date:", today)
```

Its output looks like this:

> Today's date: 2022-12-27

Note that, this also works on "synchronized" code beside with the `async` code.